# You must annotate primary keys with @NonNull (composite primary key)

Tags: java, android

I have the following Java classes in my Android project.

```
@Entity
public class Daily {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Date dailyId;

    //Other non important attrs, getters, setters, etc.

}

@Entity(primaryKeys = {"dailyId", "dailyDetailId"})
public class DailyDetail {

    private Date dailyId; //which is the value of its unique parent.
    private Long dailyDetailId;

    //Other non important attrs, getters, setters, etc.

}
```

*By the way: I did added type converters already.*

And I get the following error when I try to build the project:

```
You must annotate primary keys with @NonNull. "dailyId" is nullable. SQLite considers this a bug and Room does not allow it.
```

Then, when I follow the instructions and add @NonNull to `dailyid`, it says `Not-null fields must be initialized` (?)

How should I fix this? My idea is to initialize both primary keys, but it should be a problem when I try to insert a new object to the DB.

Comment: annotate with @NonNull and make sure you import `androidx.annotation.NonNull`

Comment: As I said in the post itself: Then, when I follow the instructions and add @NonNull to dailyid, it says Not-null fields must be initialized (?)

Comment: But did you import correct NonNull

Comment: If you are not using androidx then import `android.support.annotation.NonNull`

Comment: Without an initializer, these values could potentially be null. Give them non-null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, when I follow the instructions and add @NonNull to dailyid, it
>   says Not-null fields must be initialized (?)

If you annotate a field with `@NonNull` you're telling the compiler "this thing will never be null". But what is the default value of an uninitialized object in Java? That's right! *Null*. So if you annotate a field with `@NonNull` *you must initialize it* to guarantee that it doesn't start off null.

> How should I fix this?

Initialize your field.
Either immediately on declaration or in the class constructor.

```
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
private Date dailyId = new Date(); // Now it's initialized and not null
```

OR

```
@Entity
public class Daily {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    private Date dailyId;

    public Daily() {
        dailyId = new Date(); // Now it's initialized and not null
    }

    // ^- this AND / OR this -v

    // Note here that if using an argument in the constructor, it too must be
    // annotated as @NonNull to tell the compiler that you're setting the value
    // of your non-nullable field to something that won't itself be null
    public Daily(@NonNull Date initialDate) {
        dailyId = initialDate; // Now it's initialized and not null
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!